# Como armazeno dados numa struct e uso ela depois em funções diferentes?

Tags: c, struct

Galera estou tentando programar esse trabalho a dias e nao consigo sair do canto, é um sistema de biblioteca que por sua vez precisa:

- a) Cadastrar, visualizar, alterar e remover dados de um livro;
- b) Cadastrar, visualizar, alterar e remover novos clientes;
- c) Realizar um novo emprestimo;
- d) Realizar uma devolução;
- e) Listar todos os livros emprestados a um cliente;

Meu maior problema é armazenar os dados e usar eles novamente, eu crio o ponteiro pra uma struct e quando tento usa os dados salvo nela não consigo
segue o que conseguir fazer ate agora

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct livro{
    char titulo[81];
    char autor[41];
    char editora[31];
    int ano;
    int codigo;
};

typedef struct cliente{
    char *nome[50];
    char *cpf[11];
    char *matricula[6];     
}cliente;

int main(){
    FILE *file; 
void MenuSecundario();
void VisualizarDados();
    int opcao, menu, i;
    do
    {
    printf("\t\t\nSelecione uma das opcoes: \n");
    printf("1. Cadastrar, altera ou remover dados de cliente: \n");
    printf("2. Cadastrar, altera ou remover livro : \n");
    printf("3. Visualizar dados de clientes: \n");
    printf("4. Visualizar dados de livros: \n");
    printf("5. Realizar novo emprestimo: \n");
    printf("6. Realizar devolucao: \n");
    printf("0. Sair\n");
    printf("Opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch( opcao ){

    case 0:
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("Fechando progama...\n");
    break;
    case 1:
    system("cls || clear");
    cliente kirito;
    MenuSecundario(&kirito);
    break;
    case 2:
    system("cls || clear");

    break;
    case 3:
    VisualizarDados();
    system("cls || clear");

    break;
    case 4:
    system("cls || clear");

    break;
    case 5:
    system("cls || clear");

    break;
    case 6:
    system("cls || clear");

    break;  
    default:
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("Opcao invalida! Tente novamente.\n");
}
    } while(opcao);

    return 0;
}

void MenuSecundario(cliente *kirito[50]){
    int menu,i,aux=1;
    int pos=0;
    do{
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("Selecione uma das opcoes: \n");
    printf("1. Cadastrar novo cliente: \n");
    printf("2. Alterar dados de clientes: \n");
    printf("3. Remover cliente: \n");
    printf("0. Sair\n");
    printf("Opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &menu);


    switch(menu){

    case 0:
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("Saindo do menu...\n");
    break;
    case 1:
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("\n--------------------------Cadastrar novo cliente--------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
        while(aux==1){
    printf("Digite o nome do cliente: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &kirito[i]->nome);
    printf("Digite o cpf do cliente: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &kirito[i]->cpf);
    printf("Digite a matricula do cliente: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &kirito[i]->matricula);
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("Deseja cadastrar novo usuario ?\n");
    printf("1. sim.\n");
    printf("2. nao.\n");
    printf("opcao:");
    scanf("%d", &aux);
    system("cls || clear");
    }
}
break;

    case 2:
    system("cls || clear");

    break;

    case 3:
    system("cls || clear");

    break;
    default:
    system("cls || clear");
    printf("Opcao invalida! Tente novamente.\n");
  }
 }while(menu);
}

void VisualizarDados(cliente *kirito){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
    printf("%s", kirito->nome);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que você utilizou uma lista sequencial, na função que exibe as informações também é preciso utiliza-la.

```
void VisualizarDados(cliente *kirito) { 
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i<50; i++) { 
        printf("%s", kirito[i]->nome); //alteração nessa linha
    }
}
```

Recomendo que você utilize uma lista mais dinâmica. Esse aqui é um bom exemplo para você começar com [lista encadeada](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Listas_encadeadas).

Comment: o problema que quando faço essa alteração na linha, ela não imprime nada, como se a struct tivesse vazia sabe ?  Eu coloco pra imprimir uma mensagem qualquer, ela imprimi essa mensagem mais nao os dados q deveriam esta na struct.

Comment: Tente passar a struct que você quer visualizar como parâmetro para a função `VisualizarDados(&kirito);` e também especificar a posição que você quer exibir `kirito[i]->nome`